# hidden form field not submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, forms

I am submitting a form which has a hidden field. This hidden field is being populated by the server right when the previous page is submitted and the current one loads. So below is the code where I am populating it.

```
 $('form').on('submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url: "/connect",
        dataType:"json",
        data:$(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response){

            $('#template_request').val(JSON.stringify(response.template_request),null,2).trigger('change');
            console.log($('#template_request').val()); // this logs correctly


        },
        error: function(response){
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
```

});

I log the value in the console and it works fine. But when I submit the form, my server gets an empty value.

Relevant snippet from my HTML

```
<form>
<input class="span2" type="hidden" id="template_request" name="template_request">
....... 
</form>
```

Relevant Python code

```
req = self.get_argument('template_request')
print "Template Request"
print req
```

Comment: Check the outgoing HTTP request from the browser console to see what's actually on the wire.

Comment: what is `this` in your javascript? Is it the form? Please show all relevant submittal code

Comment: It's the form. Updated the code.

Comment: @Pointy I have checked it and it's picking up the field but not capturing the value. Right before submit, I log the value of that input field and it's captured correctly. But the form doesn't have the updated input value.

Comment: Did you try using value="" in the html <input> tag?